# ping.send by string parameter not working

Tags: c#, string, winforms, visual-studio-2017, internet-connection

I'm recently working on a **function** in C# Winform project that **checks IP connection state** (which works fine because I've tested it), and here's my code.

```
 public static bool checkConnection()
    {
        Ping pinger = new Ping();
        try
        {
            return pinger.Send("192.168.0.2").Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connection fail");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to  replace `pinger.Send("192.168.0.2").Status == IPStatus.Success;`

with the following code

```
String router_IP = "192.168.0.2";
return pinger.Send(router_IP).Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

the compiler just won't accept this kind of usage.....

Then, I tried the following code as well and it won't work neither.

```
IPAddress ip_address = IPAddress.Parse(router_IP);
return pinger.Send(ip_address).Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

So, my question is:
Does anyone know how to parse a **string variable** in `pinger.Send` instead of just sending a "192.168.0.2" ?

Here's the image of my Visual Studio 2017 (Sorry it has Chinese sayings, I will translate the suggestions provided by VS 2017)

[The error message I got from VS 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNPw.png)
The error message says: "It needs object to look up reference, so it can use non-static method or properties "FileUpload.router_IP"

Comment: `the compiler just won't accept this kind of usage...` - What happens exactly? It _should_ work, it certainly does for me.

Comment: Should work, are you sure resharper or Visual studio just isn't falsely underlining it or playing shenanigans . does it compile?

Comment: Please provide the exact error it provided.

Comment: The code looks good to me. Make sure something else isn't providing error.

Comment: @Equalsk My Visual Studio 2017 underlines the router_IP in pinger.Send(router_IP).Status

Comment: OK, and when you hover over that red line, what does it say is wrong? That router_IP doesn't exist in the current context or something similar?

Comment: @MikeRays Does it compile?

Comment: @Saruman in underlines "router_IP" and I can't compile with success

Comment: @MikeRays we are getting somewhere, what does the error say?

Comment: SO WHAT HAPPENS? If you hover over the red line on router_IP, what is the error? What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @Equalsk I just uploaded the error image of VS 2017. Sorry I don't know how to edit the image with preview. I'm a newbie to StackOverFlow.

Comment: That's not the example with the string...

Comment: @Equalsk Sorry for not being noticed. The string is being assigned somewhere else, but it contains "192.168.0.2". I just wanted to clear for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you're just missing the `static` keyword.

Your code looks something like this:

```
string router_IP = "192.168.0.2";

public static bool checkConnection()
{
    Ping pinger = new Ping();

    try
    {
        return pinger.Send(router_IP).Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connection fail");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Change the first line to this:

```
static string router_IP = "192.168.0.2";
```

Notice it's now prefixed with `static`.

Now go read about [the static keyword in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Alternatively you can change your method to accept the `string` representation of the IP address as a parameter:

```
public static bool checkConnection(string router_IP)
{
    Ping pinger = new Ping();

    try
    {
        return pinger.Send(router_IP).Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connection fail");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you just call it like so:

```
var result = checkConnection("192.168.0.2");
```

Comment: Thanks Equalsk, you saved my day!
It works when I declared the variable as 'static string'.